# Copying Pasting Word 2007 docs to HTML WYSIWYG editors

Tags: html, css, ms-word, wysiwyg, word-2007

Microsoft word has a ton of proprietary formatting and styles that do not translate well to html WYSIWYG editors.   When you paste them over to the html editor and try to edit the pasted info it causes all kinds of clashing styles.    I want to be able to keep the general structure but leave out the proprietary stuff.   Essentially I want to save clients the headache of having to completely strip out all formatting forcing them to redo all the styling again in the WYSIWYG, but at the same time avoid the conflicts that Word formatting creates.   Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need/want to do this in-browser usng JavaScript, or on the server, or the end-user's machine e.g. using some .NET software?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like the [TinyMCE paste plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/paste) work?

Answer (score 1):

The DevExpress html editor has a "paste from Word" option that mostly works.

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxHTMLEditorDemos/Dialogs/SpellChecking.aspx
See the "paste from Word" button on the toolbar.

They also have a document import (haven't tried it yet).

Answer (score 0):

I have always advised clients to paste their content into notepad first before copying it over into something like TinyMCE.